# Automatically modify bluetooth settings when launching an app

Tags: bluetooth, automation

Here is my use case: my phone is connected to my car via bluetooth, with only the `Phone audio` enabled.  `Media audio` is off, so I can keep listening to the phone's GPS and the car's radio at the same time.
But from time to time, I'd like to listen to Spotify directly through the car's audio system, which means I have to switch the bluetooth connection's `Media audio` back on.

Is it possible to automate that ?

> While connected to the car's bluetooth, if Spotify is launched, enable the connection's `Media audio`.

Perhaps with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) or [IFTTT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt&hl=en), but I couldn't find how to do it with IFTTT, and I couldn't find a way to try Tasker for free.

Comment: As for Tasker: Definitely possible. 7 day free trial available, see our [tasker tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info).

Comment: Just installed the trial.  Very sadly, it's possible to toggle `Phone Audio` (called `Bluetooth Voice` in Tasker), but not `Media Audio` (or at least I couldn't find it)... :(

Comment: I never had the need for that, so I didn't check into it. Be welcome to take a look at my [Tasker resource collection](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) (especially see the graph close to the page end for what's "hidden" where). Several things may need an addon (or simply work easier with one). In your case, wouldn't simply raising the media volume solve your issue?

Comment: Try Trigger or MacroDroid?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Bluetooth device, routing audio through it may only be possible using SCO. Try automating it with [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) (free), it has an [Bluetooth SCO set state](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/bluetooth_sco_set_state.html) block.